# Variable not setting or for loop not working correctly

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

i'm having an issue with setting a variable to the return value of a function i made i can't seem to be able to get it to work and i get no errors or feedback from visual studios even in strict mode

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form2
    Dim i As Integer
    Public CleanSearchTexts As String()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy = False Then
            i = RichTextBox1.Lines.Count
            i = i - 1
            BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        Else
            MsgBox("Threads are busy")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartThreads()
        Dim SearchText As String
        For count = count To i
            SearchText = LineFunc(count)
            count += 1
            SearchText = CType(Ask_Query(SearchText), String)
            SearchText = CType(Bing_Query(SearchText), String)
            SearchText = CType(Yahoo_Query(SearchText), String)
            Dim thread_count As String = CType(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count - 20, String)
            Label_T(thread_count)
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
            If SearchText.Contains("All_Query:Yes") Then
                SearchText = SearchText.Replace("All_Query:Yes", "")
                RTB(SearchText)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Delegate Sub UpdateStatus(ByVal s As String)
    Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal thread_count As String)
    Public Delegate Function GetTextBox(ByVal index As Integer) As String

    Public Function LineFunc(ByVal index As Integer) As String
        If InvokeRequired Then
            Invoke(New GetTextBox(AddressOf LineFunc), index)
        Else
            Dim indexSearchText As String
            indexSearchText = RichTextBox1.Lines(index)
            Return indexSearchText
        End If
    End Function


    Public Sub RTB(ByVal s As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New UpdateStatus(AddressOf RTB), New Object() {s})
        Else
            RichTextBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine & s)
        End If

    End Sub

    Public Sub Label_T(ByVal thread_count As String)
        If Me.InvokeRequired Then
            Me.Invoke(New UpdateLabel(AddressOf Label_T), New Object() {thread_count})
        Else
            Label3.Text = "Threads Running:   " + thread_count
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True

        Dim count As Integer
        Dim num As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text) - 1
        For count = 0 To num
            Dim thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf StartThreads)
            thread.IsBackground = True
            thread.Name = "Web Thread #" + CType(count, String)
            thread.Start()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        MsgBox("Work is done")
    End Sub
End Class
```

the issue is clearly with either the line getting function or the for count 
i have tested the function by adding a button and doing the process of setting a variable to the return and msgboxing it and it works perfectly not only that when i breakpoint it it shows it's returning the right output but its just not setting it for whatever reason in this sub

```
    Public Sub StartThreads(ByVal List As Object)
    Dim List2 As String() = CType(List, String())
    For Each dork As String In List2
        dork = CType(Ask_Query(dork), String)
        dork = CType(Bing_Query(dork), String)
        dork = CType(Yahoo_Query(dork), String)
        Dim thread_count As String = CType(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count - 20, String)
        Label_T(thread_count)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        If dork.Contains("All_Query:Yes") Then
            dork = dork.Replace("All_Query:Yes", "")
            RTB(dork)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

and here is the function

```
Public Delegate Function GetTextBox(ByVal index As Integer) As String

Public Function LineFunc(ByVal index As Integer) As String
    If InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New GetTextBox(AddressOf LineFunc), index)
    Else
        Dim indexSearchText As String
        indexSearchText = RichTextBox1.Lines(index)
        Return indexSearchText
    End If
End Function
```

Update: List Split Func

```
Public Function splitData(ByVal width As Integer, ByVal dd As List(Of String)) As List(Of List(Of String))

    Dim dds As New List(Of List(Of String))


    Dim numberOfLists As Integer = (dd.Count \ width)

    For i As Integer = 0 To numberOfLists
        Dim newdd As List(Of String)
        newdd = dd.Skip(i * width).Take(width).ToList()
        dds.Add(newdd)
    Next i

    Return dds
End Function
```

Updated Background Worker

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True

    Dim dds As New List(Of String)
    GetList(dds)
    Dim num As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim ThreadCount As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    If ThreadCount > 1 Then
        ThreadCount -= 1
    End If
    Dim RTBLines As Integer = RTB_Lines()
    num = CInt(RTBLines / num)
    num = CInt(Math.Ceiling(num))
    Dim splitdd As List(Of List(Of String)) = CType(splitData(num, dds), List(Of List(Of String)))
    For count = 0 To ThreadCount
        Dim ListArray As String() = splitdd(count).ToArray
        Dim newthread As New Thread(AddressOf StartThreads)
        newthread.Name = "Web Thread #" + CType(count, String)
        newthread.Start(ListArray)
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You start multiple threads calling the same method which modifies _**class level variables**_. You are not handling concurrency at all. -- Also, doing `SearchText = ...` will **change** the string each time instead of adding to it. However I am not sure if this is part of your problem or if you want it to be this way.

Comment: I also don't find it very clear what is not working. For instance: how do you know it's not working? Could you give an example of what you get and the expected output?

Comment: yes i expect it to output into the textbox2 but instead it adds blank spaces because when i do SearchText = LineFunc(count) it does not set it to anything so it adds literally a empty line

Comment: Well once again you are having concurrency issues. Multiple threads modifying the same variable(s) usually gives _very_ unpredictable results, which are also most likely different every time. -- Though your problem with the function not returning anything is fully logical: when your function invokes itself you are not getting the return value from it. You should even have a warning saying that your function  _"does not return a value on all code paths"_. Your `Invoke()` line must be changed to: `Return Invoke(New GetTextBox(AddressOf LineFunc), index)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent thank you very much i see the issue i had now i just wasn't understanding the code how would i try to get concurrent results I've made other threads about this and no one has yet to help me out with it

Comment: @VisualVincent i mean i can re-write the program i have a couple ideas with arrays to proccess arrays divided by the amount inputted and some other ideas but would there be any thing to do with what i have threading wise?

Comment: As far as I can see from my phone, your overall threading is fine. But the concurrency must be dealt with. I don't think there's any need for arrays, just declare new variables in each thread instead (if possible). If not, use arrays (or preferrably [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)) will do.

Comment: I'm wondering how i would declare new variables in threads if i want them to run a single sub without having to write a sub for each thread which objectively would be a fail i am working on a sub to divide the text i have one here but i would have to read on what List(of T) is

Comment: @VisualVincent Ah yea this is what i was doing so i'm trying it heres what i  modified i updated thread

Comment: A `List(Of T)` is like an array, but with dynamic size. You can add to it/remove from it without needing to specify the array size. -- To declare a new variable for each thread, take your `count` variable as an example. If you don't modify the class level `count` you could just write your `For`-loop like this instead: `For c = count To i`, then just use `c` instead: `SearchText = LineFunc(c)`. -- Also **you shouldn't** increment the variable itself unless you know what you're doing. Your `count += 1` line is automatically done by your `For`-loop.

Comment: A little note for when dealing with multiple threads: Always try to make a thread sub as **stand-alone** as possible.

Comment: @VisualVincent Thank you so much i had alot to change but it ended up working extremely well and fast especially when i changed the http request methods and such